# How to pipe information into a buffer to recall in unix shell

Tags: shell

I want to know how to pipe text from a cat or anything so i can use it as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using bash​:

```
FOO=$(cat foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

if using bash, no need `cat`

```
var=$(<file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable to the result of a command using `'` characters, like this:

```
$ var='cat foo'
```

This approach works in most shells.

Comment: Better to not use in space in the first row, it can interpret its as  a command.

Comment: @Ratinho Not "can", but "will".  Payne means to say var=\`cat foo\` (no spaces, and no leading $, and backticks instead of single quotes).  Backticks is equivalent to $(), which is the preferred notation.

Comment: Oops, sloppy on my part.  The $ is part of the shell prompt

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood you.
u can pipe to stdin with FIRST_COMMAND | SECOND_COMMAND.
if you want to use really variable u should write

```
$var=`COMMAND`
```

Comment: You must omit the leading '$'.